# Assign Icon to file type that is different from the assigned software icon

Tags: c#, windows

Posting this here since there is no good example on how to do that, even the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type?redirectedfrom=MSDN) isn't clear about it.

There are many examples, but none (that I found) solves the problem of software association icon override.

My software has different file types. I would like to have a specific icon for each file types, while keeping the association with my software.

With most methods, it is possible to assign an icon to a filetype, but this will be overridden by the software icon if the file is associated with the software.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the following:

```
var path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
var icopath = "c:/whatever/icon.ico";
var softwareId = "MySoftware";
var ext = ".myfiletype";


bool isElevated = false;
using (WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(identity);
    isElevated = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
}

if (isElevated)
{
    Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" + ext, "", softwareId + ext);
    Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" + softwareId + ext + @"\DefaultIcon", "", icopath);
    Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" + softwareId + ext + @"\shell\open\command", null, path + " \"%1\"");

    // refresh
    SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```